# Can a compare_exchange_strong/weak potentially see an older value?

Tags: c, atomic, c11, compare-and-swap

I implemented a concurrent algorithm where I utilize lots of compare and exchanges. Now, I want to optimize the throughput by playing around with the memory ordering, which lead me to a few particular questions. It basically boils down to the following code construct:

```c
atomic_int x = 0;

void thread1() {
  int a = atomic_load_explicit(&x, memory_order_relaxed);
  compare_exchange_strong_explicit(&x, &a, 1, memory_order_relaxed, memory_order_relaxed);
  a = atomic_load_explicit(&x, memory_order_relaxed);
}

void thread2() {
  int a = 0;
  compare_exchange_strong_explicit(&x, &a, 2, memory_order_relaxed, memory_order_relaxed);
}
```

Now assume that the compare_exchange of thread 2 succeeds, it could still happen that thread1 loads the old value 0. **However, could the compare-exchange of the first thread succeed as well, because the underlying operation still sees the old (expected) value?**

If no, then the compare-exchange must obviously fail in this case. But what about the second load? **Could it still read the old value as well due to relaxed memory ordering? Does the compare_exchange "force" a refresh in the memory subsystem for this particular thread?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are the function definitions for `atomic_load_explicit` and `compare_exchange_strong_explicit`? Is `atomic_int` user-defined?

Comment: @kiner_shah They refer to the regular C11 atomics, see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All atomic operations on a specific atomic object are guaranteed to be visible to each thread in the same so-called modification order of the object, that is they always appear consistently. (Otherwise the whole idea of atomics would not make much sense to me, anyhow.)

On the other hand, when exactly individual threads perceive the changes is entirely up to the "implementation", that is the compiler and/or runtime. Because architectures are much different in what you could expect, here, this is a what the C standard calls a "quality of implementation" issue, that is you'd have to complain to your compiler writer or chip constructor if you think that they are too slow on this, e.g.

Comment: Okay, so does that mean a compare_exchange could theoretically succeed twice even though both threads expect the same old value simply because they did not see each others store?

Comment: @user16084771 both can do their thing one after the other without interleaving. Who would be first and who would be second could be arbitrary. But nevertheless all changes of the object are performed one after another, and that order is perceived the same by both threads.